# Faceted Search With NEST

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I was going to use the faceted search feature of Elasticsearch client NEST. Unfortunately, it seems that version 2 introduced lots of breaking changes. Especially, elimination of all the functionality related to the faceted search. Is there any way to use the feature except using the raw JSON API of Elasticsearch?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/facets.html

Comment: Facets are superseded by Aggregations since Elasticsearch 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out an issue on github that clears things up. The facets feature isn't available in elasticsearch anymore.

> Facets has been replaced by Aggregations since Elasticsearch 1.0

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/1060#issuecomment-702038638